# Please help me identify this Jamie Oliver cookbook

Tags: cookbook

My wife wants a Jamie Oliver cookbook for Christmas.  All I know is that "it's the one with the pizza dough recipe."  Does anyone know which one this is?

Comment: To be snarky, almost every Jamie book has a pizza recipe in. Jamie at Home has the greatest variety, but you'll find one in 30 Min Meals, Kitchen, Does... and almost all the others.

Comment: Did anyone notice how in a majority of his cooking videos he always recommends adding a bit of lemon zest >_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jamie at home. See http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/pizza-recipes/pizza-dough